# How to add element to existing css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to add css element to my existing css class?

CSS:

```
.usrgrid {
    color:blue;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Is there any way to add attribute to `.usergrid`?

I had try like `$(.usergrid).css("display","block");` but it's not working.

Thanks.

```js
 $(".usergrid .k-button").css({ "display": "block" });
```

```css
.usergrid .k-button{
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be in quotes like `$('.usrgrid').css("display","block");`

Comment: Sounds like set display block for the class .usergrid using jquery

Comment: Please make sure first you included the jquery library then only your code will work

Comment: $('.usergrid').css({"display":"block"});

Comment: is it `css element` or `css properties`

Comment: but what if the usrgrid class is not used in any of the html element but i want add new attribute to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot add stuff to the parsed CSS. You can only add inline styles to a particular element. Say, you had a `<div class="usrgrid">`. The only modification you do it this: `<div class="usrgrid" style="color: red">`. Examples presented here using `.css` do exactly this.

Other options are:

1. Add CSS code dynamically
2. Link CSS file dynamically

**Update**

So, I realised now from where the problem comes. You have an element, you want to modify it somehow. For example, it was invisible and then became visible or it had the white background and then became yellow, whatever. The key point here is that you have your initial state and "modifier" for it. If you take the modifier away, you get back to where things began. From CSS point of view it means:

```
.my-elem {}

.my-elem--big {}

.my-elem--yellow {}

.my-elem--visible {}
```

Now, in your JS you only need to add a proper set of modifiers (classes) to you element.

```
<div class="my-elem"></div>

<div class="my-elem my-elem--visible"></div>
```

There is a naming convention for CSS called BEM. It solved exactly this problem. In a nutshell, you split your UI into blocks, elements and modifiers.

By following this approach you separate concerns (the logic of when the element should become visible, JS, and what does it mean that it is visible, CSS) and make your code more pleasant to work with (ubiquitous structure and predictability).

I personally, always try to avoid any CSS in my JS. Even if it just `display: block`. Because these two are meant for different things.

Comment: Thanks for edits @Ouroborus! my kid is running around and could only give rough answer

Comment: which mean without using the class, i cant add css properties to the class?@Ivan

Comment: Okay. Class comes from CSS and being applied to DOM elements. The intuition is that you `classify` DOM elements. Something like "green link", "big header", or even both, etc. Thus, if you want to add something extra (from the styling point of view) to your DOM element, you add either inline CSS or another class to the class list.

Comment: @AustinHoh It's possible to modify CSS classes directly via Javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/ouroborus/t4jgecoL/ Though it's rather involved to do so with stylesheet objects created from regular stylesheets.

Comment: A small correction: by doing this, you extend/overwrite the original CSS class. However, the "original" CSS code stays the same. As I mentioned before, this is the case with adding CSS dynamically to the page.

Comment: @IvanDemchenko. Now i able to change the css through jquery but it just temporary and then change back to normal. From the breakpoint, I was able to see the changes but once the function end then it back to normal.

Comment: I'm not sure, I understood the situation you've described. Anyway, the best option would be to add another class using one of the existing naming convention (I'd recommend BEM) and then toggle that class.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
  $('.usergrid').css("display","block");
```

Comment: but what if the usrgrid class is not used in any of the html element but i want add new attribute to it?

Comment: You have to use ID, Class Name or element name instead of exiting class

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the following syntax to set multiple css properties:

```
$('.usergrid').css({"display": "block", "background-color": "white"});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.usergrid').css("display","block"); 
});
</script>
```